# Как делается блокировка пользователя asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Подскажите, можно ли какими-то встроенными способами заблокировать пользователя. То смотрю, что в базовом IdentityUser
есть такие поля как: `LockoutEnd`, `LockountEnabled`.
 Можно ли сделать через IdentityUser как-то или это надо создавать отдельные поля и делать например через политики(policy)? То есть установить какое-то значение, и пользователь не сможет входить в систему.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, Lockout включен по умолчанию при добавление `AddIdentity` (соответственно и его настройки там). Вам лишь надо проверить, что бы у методов авторизации, значение `lockoutOnFailure` было в true. Суть работы проста: При неверной авторизации пользователя идет отсчет его попыток, если попытки выше указанного в настройках значения, то аккаунт закрывается на строк, который также указан в настройках.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не точно описал видимо. Мне нужно, именно чтобы можно было заблокировать пользователя. И запрещен вход в систему. Имею ввиду, не при неправильном логине чтобы блокировалось

Comment: @AK Может подскажите, там написано нужно вписать в UserManager: `UserManager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault .... 
UserManager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan .....
` И все не пойму, где это вообще вписывать надо, чтобы работало. Ибо в UserManager самом негде